# How to run Gazelle on list of directories

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-gazelle

### Context

I have a list of directories

```
- libs
  - lib1
  - lib2
  - lib3
  ...
- bin
- WORKSPACE
- BUILD.bazel
...
```

And I'd like to run gazelle on a subset of these directories that I've whitelisted.

I have hundreds of directories under `libs/` and I want to incrementally rollout gazelle.

### Question

Can I pass a filegroup to gazelle of the directories that it should check or is there some way to limit which directories gazelle goes over?

Comment: did you try this `bazel run //:gazelle -- subdir`

Comment: That might not be scalable if I have to pass 30 subdirs. Is there a way to pass a list of subdirs to the gazelle rule (as opposed to `bazel run //:gazelle`)?

Comment: what about `bazel run //:gazelle -- subdir1 subdir2` ?

Comment: If there are 30 subdirs, then the command will be too long. If there's no other approach, then it will have to do. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments have indicated, `gazelle` accepts directory names on the command line, eg `bazel run //:gazelle -- dir1 dir2`.

If there are a lot of directories, try listing them out in a file then use a combination of `cat` and `xargs`. For example, `cat dirs | xargs bazel run //:gazelle`.